# Mongoose 2dsphere not created and manual indexing works partially

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, 2dsphere

I'm new to MongoDB and Mongoose. I'm trying to create a user model with location field indexed.

```
const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    /*...*/
    location: {
        type: { type: String },
        coordinates: [Number],
    },
    /*...*/
});

userSchema.index({ location: "2dsphere" });
```

After schema definition, I tried adding 100 users with same lat,lng. Now, when I perform `$geoNear` it threw me error saying `'no geo indices for geoNear'`. So, I manually created index for location field on users collection using `MongoDB Compass`. Then, when I try the following query,

```
  User.aggregate([
    {
        $geoNear: {
            near: {
                type: "Point",
                coordinates: [lat, lng]
            },
            distanceField: "dist.calculated",
            maxDistance: 2,
            spherical: true
        }
    }]);
```

I receive only few records out of 100 records I had created. I'm unable to understand why all records isn't appearing even though the lat and lng are same.

My questions are as follows

1. Why `userSchema.index({ location: "2dsphere" });` didnt create index in the first place?
2. Why am I receiving only few records even when all lat and lng are same?

Comment: 2dsphere needs the coordinates array to be `[lng, lat]`.  If the second value in the pair is greater than 90, it won't be recognized as a coordinate.

Comment: I followed it the same way it has been mentioned on https://mongoosejs.com/docs/geojson.html. The value I store will be something like this `{ type: "Point", coordinates: [12.9929009, 77.7028336] }`

Comment: `[12.9929009, 77.7028336] ` is in the greenland sea, if you mean near Bengaluru, try using `[77.7028336, 12.9929009]`.   Notice that the examples in the documentation you linked list longitude first, like `[-109, 41]`

Comment: Okay will try changing that. Any idea why indexing is not working?

Comment: Try `User.find()` to make sure the data looks like you expect, and check via the mongo shell that the index was created.

Comment: Without manual index creation, no indexes are found in mongo shell. So I created via mongodb compass. When I perform query without $geoNear I receive all users.

Comment: If you have data in the coordinates field that isn't valid, the index will fail to be created.  That includes any documents where `coordinates` is an empty array.

Comment: But I don't have any users with zero coordinates. All my users have same coordinates. `{type:"point", coordinates:[77.7028336,12.9929009]}`

Comment: Try creating the index in the shell, see if it complains about anything.

Comment: No error received. It got created.